# How do I open a public hardcore only game?

Tags: diablo-iii

How do I open a public hardcore only game?

Comment: Next time, you should try not to use all caps for your title, use proper capitalization and include more details instead of adding meaningless filler

Answer (score 2):

All online games opened by hardcore are for hardcore only. So all you need to do is just open a public game with your hardcore, and it'll automatically be hardcore only.

Answer (score 0):

Log in with your hardcore character (possible once you reached level 10 with a softcore character), start a game in the act you want, and then press `ESC` and make the game public.